# django templates working with external js files

Tags: django-templates

i have some javascript code in Django templates like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    pager.init(); 
    pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition'); 
    pager.showPage(1); </script>
```

corresponding functions are in external js file...but these are not calling js functions i guess.so pagination is not working...any clue would be great ..and no errors in Firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked for me when i wrapped it in block inside the parent template {% if XXX %} goes here {%endif%} ....may not be great but it worked for me.

Comment: please provide example, to clarify this